# Finding Bilinear Form with Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

This is a given Bilinear form (of Matrix) :

> $$B(X,Y)=\operatorname{tr}(XY)$$

I need to find a base in case of $n=2$ (matrix size is $2\times 2$) that the form B-form is represented by Diagonal matrix.

I think the base can be found with Gram–Schmidt process, but I don't know how to solve it.

Please help me with that, Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to represent $X$ and $Y$ as $4-$dimensional vectors, so that $\mathrm{tr}(XY) = x^TBy?$

Comment: Yes, represent X and Y as 4−dimensional vectors.

Comment: Then I suggest writing $X = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, $Y= (y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)$, and writing $B$ out as an arbitrary four-by-four matrix, then computing $X^T B Y$. Then you'll see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, but now I think that X & Y should be 2x2 matrices. So my question is - Do I need to calc B(i,j) for the base {e1,..,e4} while e1 is ( (1,0) (0,0) ) ? In which step do I have to use GS ?

Comment: If you want to formally keep $X$ and $Y$ as matrices I believe you'll have to define $B$ in a more general way, as a bilinear map $B: V \times V \rightarrow F$, where $F$ is the base field (say $\mathbb{C}$). Note that $XBY$ is a matrix, not a number. What you will probably want to do, actually, is diagonalize $B$, i.e. $B=PDP^{-1}$, and then write $X$ and $Y$ relative to the basis $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$B\left(\pmatrix{x_1&x_2\\x_3&x_4},\pmatrix{y_1&y_2\\y_3&y_4}\right)=x_1y_1+x_2y_3+x_3y_2+x_4y_4$$
A basis of $2\times 2$ matrices is given by $e_1:=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$, $e_2:=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$, $e_3:=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$, $e_4:=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$.

Then you can try to apply the Gram-Schmidt process. Calculate $B(e_i,e_j)$ and then $f_1:=e_1$ (its $B$-norm is already $1$), then
$$f_2:=e_2-B(f_1,e_2)f_1$$
and so on..

Comment: should it be `f2:=e2-B(e2,f1)f1` ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, as $B$ is symmetric: $tr(XY)=tr(YX)$ (you can verify it by calculation).. Have you found these $f_2,f_3,f_4$?